# rs_graphics.rsh part of Renderscript graphics engine that has been deprecated?

Tags: android, renderscript

I just started to use the Renderscript. I saw some renderscript examples under the "sdk/samples/android-15/RenderScript" folder, which have the line:`#include "rs_graphics.rsh"`

In examples under "sdk/samples/android-18", I don't see that line any more. I understand that the Renderscript graphics engine has been deprecated. I'd like to confirm that "rs_graphics.rsh" is part of the deprecated engine, and should not be used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct, rs_graphics.rsh has been deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Tim Murray: Thanks for the confirmation. I assume the reason why "rs_graphics.rsh" has been deprecated is because it is part of the Renderscript graphics engine?

Comment: yeah, it's all functions specifically for graphics. the objects used within require a RenderScriptGL context in order to be created in the first place, and RenderScriptGL was deprecated.

Comment: My codes are old and still using rs_graphics so what alternatives I got?